# Why does facebook uses margin-left: -9999px to hide elements?

Tags: css

I was playing with firebug in Facebook's stream and I've noticed something funny on the style of the "update options" menu (that down arrow button that appears on the top right of the update when you hover over it). It seems to me that they hide this menu by setting margin-left: -9999px, and show them by overriding this with margin-left: auto. I can't think of a reason to do this instead of display: none. Is there any reason for doing it this way?

Comment: As I am not Facebook, I can only speculate, but it may be a means of avoiding accessibility issues using `display:none` which makes screen readers pretend it's not even in the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an accessibility thing. Text with *display: none* also does not show up on screenreaders. You can read up on it at [CSS in Action: Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).

Comment: Shouldn't @media be used instead?

Comment: Yeah should. But I don't know about a screen reader that brings its own HTML rendering engine or honors the media type any other way. From what I know they do exactly what it says: screen reading. So you are also at the mercy of the browser.

Comment: Is there any benefit to this method (margin-left) as opposed to text-indent: -9999px? The only thing I can think of is for hiding full paragraphs of text where there are <br /> tags present.